# Permanent JMS Connection failure but no error

Tags: java, spring, jms, ibm-mq, spring-integration

I have 3 servers - 2 servers running identical spring integration applications and 1 websphere MQ server. Both applications connect to the same topic.

After what seems like an unpredictable amount of time (sometimes hours, sometimes days) both applications stop receiving messages. This failure occurs on both applications at approximately the same time. The applications require a restart in order to recover.

Both applications have the following config:

```
<bean id="jmsInputFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQTopicConnectionFactory">
    <property name="queueManager" value="MyQM" />
    <property name="hostName" value="x.x.x.x" />
    <property name="port" value="15004" />
    <property name="transportType" value="1" />
    <property name="channel" value="MYCHANNEL" />
    <property name="clientId" value="${system.description}"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="cachedConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jmsInputFactory"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsDestinationResolver"
    class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver" />

<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter 
    channel="myChannel" 
    connection-factory="cachedConnectionFactory"
    destination-resolver="jmsDestinationResolver"
    pub-sub-domain="true"
    destination-name="MYTOPIC" />
```

I can't seem to find any error message anywhere and am at a loss for how to go about further investigation. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Before starting to not receive messages anymore, has there been idle period of time when there were no message in topic to be consumed?

Comment: We're receiving approximately 10 messages per second so there shouldn't be much idle period

Comment: What does "I can't seem to find any error message anywhere" mean exactly? Stack trace? Client side error logs? QMgr error logs? WMQ global error logs? Client side trace? Server-side trace?  In order to suggest next steps, it's helpful to know what, exactly, you've already looked at.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem; some networks (firewalls, routers) silently drop idle connections; if the vendor client is not informed of the socket closure, then no exception is propagated up the stack to force a reconnect.

The usual solution to these issues is to enable heartbeats of some kind to keep idle sockets active (from the network's perspective). Refer to your JMS vendor's documentation on how to set that up.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Gary. Would the sockets be idle is messages were on the topic? We get roughly 10 messages per second

Comment: No; they would normally only be idle if there is a period of time with no data. But in any case, your symptoms would indicate the socket is dead, but the client doesn't know it. Again, heartbeats would solve that.